# Multiple params type parameters in mehods in c#

Tags: c#, .net, parameters

In case of situations to use multiple params type parameters in methods what is the alternate because i get error while trying to use multiple params type parameters

Comment: Post your method header

Comment: Why would you need multiple params type parameters..

Comment: Explain to us *why* you would want to use multiple params type parameters. We know *what* you want to do, but that don't work. If you tell us *why* then we can give you the best alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use plain arrays instead:

```
public void Method( /*remove params*/ string[] first
                  , /*optionally remove params*/ int[] second
                  )
{ }
```

Call it:

```
Method(new string[] { ... }, new int[] { ... } );
```

Optionally, you could leave the last `params` as is, since it can only be one per method and must be the last one, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx):

> No additional parameters are permitted after the params keyword in a method declaration, and only one params keyword is permitted in a method declaration.

Answer (score 1):

For simplistic use, I'd go with the solution Patrick Hofman supplied. Although, whenever you want to do something more type specific and including a wider range of types, I'd say you should be using `params`.

```
    public class Bar { }

    public void Foo(params object[] objs)
    {
        foreach(object obj in objs)
        {
            Type typeofObject = obj.GetType();
            if (typeofObject == typeof(string))
            {
                // Its a string
            }
            else if (typeofObject == typeof(int))
            {
                // Its an integer
            }
            else if (typeofObject == typeof(Bar))
            {
                // Its an Bar object
            }
        }
    }
```

Calling the method:

```
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        this.Foo("hi", 1, bar);
```

But again, this isn't the right solution if you only have 2/3 types.

Comment: 'OP uses 2'? I don't really get that part, 2 what? Types? He stated multiple types, that could be 5 or even 10.

Comment: Then my code does answer his question? He can supply all types he wants to my method, but as I said: it depends on the way he wants to use his types inside the method.